# Data is not being saved

Tags: java

I have this sample output

[image]

Data entered should be saved, for example; going back and entering again for Thursday should result into "Thursday Coding: 2" yet it wont.

Here is my controller:

```
        BusName = request.getParameter("busName");
        PlateNumber = request.getParameter("plateNo");
        DriverAssigned = request.getParameter("driverAssigned");


        String firstString = PlateNumber.substring(0, 2);
        String secondString = PlateNumber.substring(3, 5);

        if (firstString.matches(".*[A-Z].*") && secondString.matches(".*\\d.*")){

        CalculatorBean beanCalc = BeanFactory.getInstance(BusName, PlateNumber, DriverAssigned);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("deJesusBean", beanCalc);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("displayresult.jsp");           
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Here is my assembler:

```
public class BeanFactory {

public static CalculatorBean getInstance(String busName, String plateNo, String driverAssigned){
    CalculatorBean calcBean = new CalculatorBean();
    calcBean.setBusName(busName);
    calcBean.setPlateNo(plateNo);
    calcBean.setDriverAssigned(driverAssigned);
    calcBean.compute();
    return calcBean;
}
```

}

Here is the logic in my model:

```
    public void compute(){
    char x = plateNo.charAt(5);

    if (x == '1' || x == '2'){
        dayOfCoding = "Monday";
        mondayCoding = mondayCoding + 1;
    }
    else if (x == '3' || x == '4'){
        dayOfCoding = "Tuesday";
        tuesdayCoding = tuesdayCoding + 1;
    }
    else if (x == '5' || x == '6'){
        dayOfCoding = "Wednesday";
        wednesdayCoding = wednesdayCoding + 1;
    }
    else if (x == '7' || x == '8'){
        dayOfCoding = "Thursday";
        thursdayCoding = thursdayCoding + 1;
    }
    else if (x == '9' || x == '0'){
        dayOfCoding = "Friday";
        fridayCoding = fridayCoding + 1;
```

and here is how I call it on my displayResult.jsp

```
    ${deJesusBean.tuesdayCoding}
```

Would appreciate your help. Sorry if the post was again written, I clarified things here now.